# Loading spinner stays on if middle click link in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, spinner

I have a page that uses the spin.js (http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/#!) pure Javascript spinner to show a spinner when a link (to a slow page) is clicked. I trigger it using onclick on the link.

The problem is in Chrome (v 30.0.1599.69 m) if I middle-button-click on the link to open the slow page in a new tab, then when I return to the original page the spinner is running and keeps running forever. It does not happen in IE or Firefox.

(Obviously if I left-click on the link the spinner will die when the new page is loaded.)

My link looks like this:
    `<a href="other-sources.php?id='.$id.'" onClick="return spinner(40);">Other Sources</a>`

And the script that starts the spinner looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Display spinner while waiting for Other Sources to display.
// Parameter is vertical position of spinner, since we have 2 Show Source links
function spinner(posn) {
    var opts = {
        lines: 15, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 7, // The length of each line
        width: 4, // The line thickness
        radius: 15, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: posn, // Top position relative to parent in px
        left: 850 // Left position relative to parent in px
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('main');
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
return true; 
}
</script>
```

To complete the picture, I have this in the Head section:

```
<script src="spin.min.js"></script>
```

Is there something I can put in the javascript to make it ignore middle button clicks? I read elsewhere that detecting the buttons is rather quirky.

Hmmm. I see there is a bug report about it dating back to 2008: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1687

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer to the question and accept it. This will do a few things for future visitors; people wishing to answer questions will see that the question is answered immediately, and people with the same issue can jump to the accepted answer and read it without having to read a massive question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem as follows:

1. Changed the link from onClick to onmouseup
2. Added the following code to the start of the javascript:

   ```
   if (event.which == null)
      /* IE case */
      var button= (event.button < 2) ? "LEFT" :
                ((event.button == 4) ? "MIDDLE" : "RIGHT");
   else
      /* All others */
      var button= (event.which < 2) ? "LEFT" :
                ((event.which == 2) ? "MIDDLE" : "RIGHT");
      if (button != "LEFT")
             return true;
   ```